# CSS flexible-height "slideUp" transition

Tags: css

A common approach for making a SlideUp transition is the following:

```
.cssSlideUp {
    transition: .5s linear all;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cssSlideUp.hide {
    height:0;
}
```

This approach requires the element to have a fixed height (`80px`).

What approach allows me to have the same effect but with a flexible height?

#### Update:

This works, but I'm still not satisfied. The `max-height:400px` property still fixes the height on a specified number, and doing `max-height:9999px` to make it "infinite" will make the transition unnoticeable:

```
.cssSlideUp {
    transition: .5s linear all;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cssSlideUp.ng-hide {
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

#### Update 2:

A scale transform works well, but I'm still not satisfied, since it won't push/pull the elements below:

```
.cssSlideUp {
    transition: .5s linear all;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cssSlideUp.ng-hide {
    transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `height: auto`?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS transition height: 0; to height: auto;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the already referenced implementations, you can also use a negative top margin combined with a container. However it suffers from the problem of margins being bound to width, not height, resulting in an unpercise animation and other implied complications.
Sample implementation is as follows: [**Jsfiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/8WTBH/)

HTML:

```
<h1>Previous content</h1>
<p>This is content before the animation.</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
        <h1>Hover anywhere to scroll up</h1>
        <p>We have some content here.</p>
        <p>But no one can be quite sure just how large this content is.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Later content</h1>
<p>This is content after the animation.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.scroll {
    transition: .5s linear all;
}

body:hover .scroll {
    margin-top: -100%;   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, nothing currently without JavaScript. Transitions require a known start and end point.

With JS you cannot check the height of an element that is not displayed because non-displayed elements have no layout. You need to clone or position the element you want the height of off the screen.

This technique is used by [jQuery Actual](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual).

There is alternatively a slight misappropriation of CSS available by setting the `max-height` of the target element and transitioning that but that's brittle.